# List file in a system folder with READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission sufficient?

Tags: java, android, file, android-permissions

In android, with READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission (already granted), is is possible to have a list of all the files in either data/app or data/local/tmp? For example:

```
File file = new File(path); //either "data/app" or "data/local/tmp"
File[] list = file.listFiles();
```

I keep getting null pointer exception when trying to read list.length(). Is it because the list of the file cannot be read without more permission? if yes, then which one?

Comment: You need a rooted phone to begin with. And then your app needs root permission.

Comment: This is what I doubted, I could see if the file "exist" or not (putting in the exact path) when I adb without su permission, could not do ls without su